# Load Json files randomly in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am having a div with *ngFor which loads values form json. I need to load values from different json files randomly.
Here the div gets value from 'mydata', next time i need to get values from another json. How can i do this?
i heard about Math.floor((Math.random(). How do i do with this? or any other methods?

```
html file 
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let data of mydata">
       <div class="col">{{data.number}}</div>
       <div class="col">{{data.code}}</div>          
      </div>



ts file

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-showall',
templateUrl: 'showall.html'
})
export class ShowallPage {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

 }

// i am providing data here instead of json for development.
  datas = [
{
  number: "1",
  code: "apple",

},
{
  number: "2",
  code: "orange",

},
{
  number: "3",
  code: "banana",

},{
  number: "50",
  code: "lemon",

}

  ];

  mydata = this.datas;

   // i am using this 'mydata' variable in *ngFor to get values

 }
```

Comment: with angular1 can I do?

Comment: im using andgular 2 in ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

In your class that you created, you specified from which JSON file you are reading and assigned it to datas.

Create an array of locations you want to read from and initialise it from your constructor.

```
public locations: Array<string>;

this.locations = ['firstLocation.json', 'secondLocation.json'];
let randomJsonFile = this.locations[Math.floor((Math.random() * this.locations.length) + 1)];
```

EDIT:
(OP added a more detailed question)

```
  // Outside of the constructor (inside of the class)

  mydata: Array<Object>;
  datas0: Array<Object>;
  datas1: Array<Object>;
  datas2: Array<Object>;
  datasCollection: Array<Object>;

  // Inside of the constructor

      this.datas0 = [
        { number: "1", code: "apple0" },
        { number: "2", code: "orange0" },
        { number: "3", code: "banana0" },
        { number: "50", code: "lemon0" }
      ];

      this.datas1 = [
        { number: "1", code: "apple1" },
        { number: "2", code: "orange1" },
        { number: "3", code: "banana1" },
        { number: "50", code: "lemon1" }
      ];

      this.datas2 = [
        { number: "1", code: "apple2" },
        { number: "2", code: "orange2" },
        { number: "3", code: "banana2" },
        { number: "50", code: "lemon2" }
      ];

      this.datasCollection.push(this.datas0, this.datas1, this.datas2);

      this.mydata = this.datasCollection[Math.floor((Math.random() * this.datasCollection.length) + 1)];
```

Comment: i am new to ionic, so can u pls explain the code
i have 5 jsons namely
one.json, two.json, three.json, four.json & five.json

i need the values from the jsons in the following code: 
 mydata = this.datas;

i am using this 'mydata' in 

*ngFor="let data of mydata">

Comment: Please update your initial question with a more detailed question and add code examples of your class.

Comment: thanks for the code, it works, but now i am getting error Runtime Error
Error in ./ShowallPage class ShowallPage - caused by: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined,